# Event To Command Issua Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Hej ,

i have a ListView bound to a ObservableCollection, and im using Event To Command instead of ItemTapped. I noticed a really weird behavior, if i add a Item to my Collection my app Crashes with following exception Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
StackTrace: http://pastebin.com/Qj77Q5j6

Now if i **change the Collection to a normal List** the App doesnt Crash anymore, but list isnt a option for me since i need the ListView to get Updated when adding items.

ListView:

```
  <ListView x:Name="ListViewPerson"
            ItemsSource="{Binding PersonCollection, Mode=TwoWay}"
            Grid.Column="0"
            SeparatorColor="Silver"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TemplateSelector}">
    <ListView.Behaviors>
      <commands:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemTapped" Command="{Binding ListViewAngebotItemTappedCommand}" EventArgsConverter="{StaticResource ItemTappedConverter}" />
    </ListView.Behaviors>
  </ListView>
```

If i remove the Event to Command behavior the List works as excpected, but im trying to not break the MVVM pattern.

Event to Command Behavior: https://blog.xamarin.com/turn-events-into-commands-with-behaviors/

Comment: Where's your code for `EventToCommandBehavior`?

Comment: This video will help you https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Abjc0wkjalU

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like a bug in Xamarin.Forms, I found that it is already filed it on Bugzilla here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=26418.

I have a very bad experience with Xamarin list view and instead of it I'm using Custom Repeaters

```
 public class CustomRepeater : StackLayout
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The Item template property
    /// </summary>
    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemTemplateProperty = BindableProperty.Create("ItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(CustomRepeater), null, propertyChanged: (bindable, oldvalue, newvalue) => ((CustomRepeater)bindable).OnSizeChanged());


    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the item template
    /// </summary>
    public DataTemplate ItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(ItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(ItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }
    public void OnSizeChanged()
    {
        this.ForceLayout();
    }

    public ScrollView RootScrollView { private set; get; }

    public StackLayout MainStackLayout { private set; get; }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        Children.Clear();

        RootScrollView = new ScrollView();
        MainStackLayout = new StackLayout();

        MainStackLayout.Children.Clear();
        IList list =BindingContext as IList;
        if (list != null)
        {
            foreach (var i in list)
            {
                var child = this.ItemTemplate.CreateContent() as View;
                if (child == null)
                {
                    return;
                }

                child.BindingContext = i;
                MainStackLayout.Children.Add(child);
            }               

            Children.Add(MainStackLayout);
        }
    }
```

in Xaml:

```
    <UserControls:CustomRepeater x:Name="repeaterUC" Grid.Row="1" BindingContext="{Binding CurrentChallenge.Over12FormQuestionsCollection}"  >
        <UserControls:CustomRepeater.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
              <Label Text="{Binding Name}" TextColor="#223568" />
              <Label Text="{Binding SelectedAnswersText}" FontAttributes="Italic"   TextColor="#223568" LineBreakMode="WordWrap"/>
            </StackLayout>
          </DataTemplate>
        </UserControls:CustomRepeater.ItemTemplate>

      </UserControls:CustomRepeater>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer this is really weird because when i use aList it works without update.... can i use this like an ListView with MVVM pattern?

Comment: yes, check the updated answer with a sample I'm already using.

Comment: thanks for your time but i have the same problem again.